# How to have access of control (Button) in another form [C#]

Tags: c#

I would like it from another form, I have the list of buttons and their properties (button1.text from another form).

```
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         button2.text = " "; //this is the button that should appear to me, which is part of the other form.
    }

}
```

the problem is that the relative property and the button itself does not appear to me. even if i do:

```
Form1 Home = New Form1();
```

Comment: Surely you don't actually want to create a new form object.  Use the designer to change the Modifiers property of the button from "Private" to "Public".

Comment: Wow thanks :) it works!